# Updating style of path within svg and d3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to update the style of a path element within a svg.

(tl;dr): I just want to highlight the fill and/or stroke of the country that is clicked on from the list.

The svg is a world map with many path nodes:

```
<svg>
    <g class="datamaps-subunits">
        <path class="datamap-subunit AFG"></path>
        <path class="datamap-subunit AGO"></path>
        // paths for every country
        <path class="datamaps-subunit NZL" data-info="{'fillKey':'partner'}" data-hasqtip="13" style="fill: rgb(184, 37, 47); stroke-width: 1; stroke-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(253, 253, 253);"></path>
        ...
    </g>
</svg>
```

With the above `html`, I'm trying to adjust the styling of a specific `<path>` element when the user clicks on the country's name from a list. I'm returning that country class ('NZL') to match the country that was clicked to the `<path>` element with the same class.

Once that is done, I just want to highlight or change the style of the clicked country's path but nothing is working.

Here's what I have:

```
$('.datamaps-subunit').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass(country)) { // in this case country = NZL

        $(this).css({ fill: "rgb(0,0,0)" })
        $(this).attr('data-info', '{"fillKey":"partnerHighlight"}')
        $(this).addClass('partner-highlight')

        // trying another way
        d3.select('.' + country).style('stroke', 'rgb(0,0,0)')
    }
})
```

All of these *work* in the sense that they are applied to the element. If I `console.log(this)` in the above function, here is what is shown:

```
<path class="datamaps-subunit NZL partner-highlight" 
    data-info="{'fillKey':'partnerHighlight'}" 
    data-hasqtip="13" 
    style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1; stroke-opacity: 1; stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" 
    aria-describedby="qtip-13">
</path>
```

All of the styles are shown as added to the element but nothing is having any effect on the actual display. What am I missing here?

***UPDATE*** Big thanks to @Shashank! The solution was to move the `data` object out of the `init()` function in the `Datamap` initializer to a variable `data`. By doing that we have access to `data` outside of `init()`.

Thus, we can alter the `data` object's `fillKey` value along with triggering the map rotation at the same time on click using this:

```
$('a[data-id]').on('click', function() {
    var long = $(this).data('longitude');
    var lat = $(this).data('latitude');
    var country = $(this).data('id');
    data[country].fillKey = data[country].fillKey === 'partner' ? 'partnerHighlight' : 'partner'; 
    rotate2Destination(long, lat, country);
})
```

Sweetness.

Comment: Two things missing: 1. Closing `</path>` for the first two paths. 2. Match the class names of the paths and the each function. (**datamaps-subunit** or **datamap-subunit**). Can you try these fixes?

Comment: @Shashank I added the closing paths - this was just a quick example. The matching happens with a click event sending the `country` argument to the function. In this case that country is `NZL` so it uses that to match the class. The matching is working as it is showing the correct `<path>` element (with the class of 'NZL' ) in the console. The `datamaps-subunits` (plural) is for the `<g>` element; the `datamaps-subunit` class is for the individual `<path>` elements.

Comment: In any event, the closing paths are in the actual HTML and the `datamaps-subunits/subunits` classes are not particularly relevant here. I'm matching the country code classes which *is* working.

Comment: if you look (DevTools) at the style applied for this `path` with `partner-highlight` what is changed? Why don't you use `d3.select("."+country).classed("partner-highlight", true);` and set in the CSS `.partner-highlight{fill:black;stroke:black;stroke-width:1;}`

Comment: Agreed. It's not relevant. As the style is being applied to the path, it does work fine - http://jsfiddle.net/shashank2104/3d4nt92q/8/ (changed the `fill` to `blue` for testing). Maybe you can show us the *actual display*.

Comment: @rioV8 I had the fill set in the css but it is having no effect. I also have the `partnerHighlight` fill property set in js (this is using `datamaps.js`). 

The issue is even with the css, the style property, and setting the `partnerHighlight` property in the datamaps js, nothing is having any effect. I've tried each of those individually as well. 

I can see it is working in the fiddle so it must be some sort of conflict — perhaps with `qtip2` or `d3` and `datamaps`? I'm pushing this up to a dev server so will have a link in a few.

Comment: @Shashank I've added a link: [https://studiobiodev.com/jb.dev/wp/partners/](https://studiobiodev.com/jb.dev/wp/partners/)

Comment: I just checked the code in the Source. The fill works fine until you redraw the paths  in the `rotate2Destination` function (`attrTween`) which calls back the `init` function initializaing **DataMap** with the original `fillKey`s. You might wanna improvise there by mapping the data with the new `fillKey`s. This way if the fillKey is *parter-highlight*, the library will take care of the rest.

Comment: @Shashank brilliant. I'll give that a go. Thanks so much.

Comment: Sure. No problem. Let me know if it turns out to be a pain in doing that. I'll try helping you out.

Comment: @Shashank welp, I'm stuck. How can I re-assign the fillKey parameter in the rotate2Destination function? Or, alternatively update the style(s) without re-initializing DataMap (or in lieu of that)? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182170/discussion-between-shashank-and-joshuaiz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full answer (all credit to @Shashank):

```
// move data property to a variable outside of init()
var data = {
    ARG: { fillKey: "partner",}, // Argentina
    AUS: { fillKey: "partner" }, // Australia
    CHL: { fillKey: "partner" }, // Chile
    CHN: { fillKey: "partner" }, // China
    CRI: { fillKey: "partner" }, // Costa Rica
    DEU: { fillKey: "partner" }, // Germany
    HKG: { fillKey: "partner" }, // Hong Kong
    IND: { fillKey: "partner" }, // India
    IDN: { fillKey: "partner" }, // Indonesia
    ITA: { fillKey: "partner" }, // Italy
    JPN: { fillKey: "partner" }, // Japan
    KOR: { fillKey: "partner" }, // Republic of Korea
    MYS: { fillKey: "partner" }, // Malaysia
    MEX: { fillKey: "partner" }, // Mexico
    NZL: { fillKey: "partner" }, // New Zealand
    PAK: { fillKey: "partner" }, // Pakistan
    PAN: { fillKey: "partner" }, // Panama
    PER: { fillKey: "partner" }, // Peru
    PHL: { fillKey: "partner" }, // Philippines
    SGP: { fillKey: "partner" }, // Singapore
    ZAF: { fillKey: "partner" }, // South Africa
    THA: { fillKey: "partner" }, // Thailand
    VNM: { fillKey: "partner" }, // Viet Nam
    USA: { fillKey: "partner" }, // United States
}

// now we can access and alter the data even with a d3.redraw()
$('a[data-id]').on('click', function() {
    var long = $(this).data('longitude');
    var lat = $(this).data('latitude');
    var country = $(this).data('id');
    // th
    data[country].fillKey = data[country].fillKey === 'partner' ? 'partnerHighlight' : 'partner'; 
    rotate2Destination(long, lat, country);
})
```

That's it.